# Test code coverage not covering the for loop

Tags: apex, apexrest

EDIT:

My latest code with the new error, I used the code suggested by sfdcfox and here is what the error I'm seeing:

> execution of BeforeInsert caused by: System.NullPointerException:
> Attempt to de-reference a null object Class.

Here is my updated code:

Trigger:

```
trigger AccountTrigger on Account (before insert, before update) {
    If (Trigger.isBefore) { 
        if (Trigger.isInsert || Trigger.isUpdate) { 
        AccountTriggerHandler.checkForDupes(Trigger.new, Trigger.oldMap);
        }
  } 
}
```

AccountTriggerHandler:

```
public class AccountTriggerHandler {
    
    public static void checkForDupes(List<Account> accNew, Map<Id, Account> accOldMap) {
       
    Set<String> accountNames = new Set<String>();
    Set<String> existingAccountNames = new Set<String>();
    for (Account acc : accNew) {
        if(!accountNames.add(acc.Name)) {
            acc.Name.addError('The account named '+acc.Name+' already exists.');
        }
    }
    for (Account acc : [SELECT Name FROM Account WHERE Name IN :accOldMap.KeySet() AND Id != :Trigger.new]) {
        existingAccountNames.add(acc.Name);
    }
    for(Account acc: accNew) {
        if(existingAccountNames.contains(acc.Name)) {
            acc.Name.addError('The account named '+acc.Name+' already exists.');
        }
    }

}
```

END EDIT

I have the following apex method that prevents the duplicate records inserted/updated.

Apex class: checkAccountNameDuplicate

```
Map<String, Account> accMap = new Map<String, Account>(); 
    for (Account acc : Trigger.new) {  
        
        if (acc.Name != Trigger.oldMap.get(acc.Id).Name)) {  
            if (accMap.containsKey(acc.Name)) {
                acc.Name.addError('Another account has the ' + acc.Name + ' same name.');
            } else {
                accMap.put(acc.Name, acc);
            }
        }
    }   
    for (Account acc : [SELECT Name FROM Account WHERE Name IN :accMap.KeySet()]) 
    {
        Account newAcc = accMap.get(acc.Name);
        newAcc.Name.addError('An account with this name ' + acc.Name + ' already exists.');
    }
}
```

Here is my test class:

```
@istest
static void testInsertNewRecord(){
    Test.startTest();
     
    Boolean exceptionThrown = false;
    
    try {  
        List<Account> accounts = new List<Account>();
        Map<Id, Account> oldmap = new Map<Id, Account>();
        Account a = new Account();
        a.Name = 'test'; 
        accounts.add(a);          
        a = new Account();
        a.Name = 'test'; 
        accounts.add(a);
    
        //inserted  
        insert accounts;  

        Account a2 = new Account(Name = 'test');
        insert a2;
        oldmap.put(a2.id, a2);

        AccountTriggerHandler.checkAccountNameDuplicate(accounts, oldmap); 
        
        
        
    } catch (Exception e) {
        exceptionThrown = true; 
        // assert
        Boolean expectedExceptionThrown =  (e.getMessage().contains(errorMessage)) ? true : false; 
        System.AssertEquals(true, expectedExceptionThrown, e.getMessage()); 
    }  
        
    System.assertEquals(true, exceptionThrown, 'No exception was thrown'); 
    Test.stopTest();
}
```

my question is why my test code coverage is not covering the second `for loop` which is:
`for (Account acc : [SELECT Name FROM Account WHERE Name IN :accMap.KeySet()])` the coverage never goes inside this for loop, any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're using a try-catch block, after the first error is added, you end up going to the catch block, so insert a2 never happens. Also, I presume that your unit test is using `before insert` as the trigger type, which means the records in the trigger context won't be queried. Also, I would add that your unit test should not be calling AccountTriggerHandler directly, because that's what the trigger is for.

Your trigger should look more like this:

```
Set<String> accountNames = new Set<String>();
Set<String> existingAccountNames = new Set<String>();
for (Account acc : Trigger.new) {
    if(!accountNames.add(acc.Name)) {
        acc.Name.addError('The account named '+acc.Name+' already exists.');
    }
}
for (Account acc : [SELECT Name FROM Account WHERE Name =  :accountNames AND Id != :Trigger.new]) {
    existingAccountNames.add(acc.Name);
}
for(Account acc: Trigger.new) {
    if(existingAccountNames.contains(acc.Name)) {
        acc.Name.addError('The account named '+acc.Name+' already exists.');
    }
}
```

As far as the unit test, you should consider using `Database.insert(accounts, false)`, and then evaluate the results from this method (`Database.SaveResult`). Do not use the try-catch block here, otherwise your unit test code can't get to the end, or you would need multiple try-catch blocks.

---

Edit: Here's the relevant unit test that achieved 100% in my org:

```
@isTest public class accountDupTest {
    @isTest static void test() {
        Account[] accounts1 = new Account[] {
            new Account(Name='test'),
            new Account(Name='test')
        };
        Account[] accounts2 = new Account[] {
            new Account(Name='test')
        };
        Database.SaveResult[] results1 = Database.insert(accounts1, false);
        Database.SaveResult[] results2 = Database.insert(accounts2, false);
        System.assert(results1[0].isSuccess(),'Expected record to save');
        System.assert(!results1[1].isSuccess(),'Expected duplicate error 1');
        System.assert(!results2[0].isSuccess(),'Expected duplicate error 2');
    }
}
```

Comment: the reason I used the `try/catch` is to cover the `addError`, how would you do without try/catch?

Comment: @Nick `Database.insert(accounts, false)`-- the second parameter is allOrNone, and when set to false, your DML operation can support some records showing errors while allowing the rest to succeed.

Comment: I updated my question and I used your suggested code but running into   null exception, can you please take a look ?

Comment: @Nick Yeah, the wrong variable was being used. I have edited my answer to reflect the change.

Comment: I have tried using `Database.insert(accounts, false)` for the test class but I'm still not able to cover my test coverage to 100 and it's not covering inside for loop lines, any idea?

Comment: @Nick I wrote up a unit test for this. Make sure your code matches exactly (as a starting point), this now definitely works in my dev org, with 100% coverage.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help @sfdcfox